# What's the difference between a positive and negative particle moving in a magnetic field?

Tags: charge, electromagnetic-induction

In the same trajectory the positive goes down and negative goes up... Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Does [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284081/how-electron-get-deflected-in-magnetic-field-while-moving/284153#284153) is what you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as asking:

"If I have two negative charges they **push each other away**, but if I have a positive and a negative charge they **pull each other in**".

This is a fundamental feature of particles. And why there exist two types of charges that are each other's opposite and act opposite in the magnetic field, is not an easy question to answer...

Answer (score 0):

It's a sign convention we follow for the ease of our understanding/calculation. In 3 dimensional space, there's nothing up or down, but direction relative to some line or plane of reference.

Your diagram just shows the direction of deflection of charged particles in the presence of a magnetic field B.

The force on any particle traveling through a magnetic field is qBv where q is the charge on the particle, B is the magnetic field and v is the velocity with which the particle moves. When q=0, force is 0. When q  has charge associated to it has a value, force has significant quantity, and force being vector quantity, is always associated with a direction.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic Lorentz force is:
$$\vec{F}=q\left(\vec{v}\times \vec{B}\right)=q\begin{vmatrix}\vec{i}&\vec{j}&\vec{k}\\
\vec{v_{x}}&\vec{v_{y}}&\vec{v_{z}}\\
\vec{B_{x}}&\vec{B_{y}}&\vec{B_{z}}
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$\vec{F}=q\left[\left(v_{y}B_{z}-v_{z}B_{y}\right)\vec{i}+\left(v_{z}B_{x}-v_{x}B_{z}\right)\vec{j}+\left(v_{x}B_{y}-v_{y}B_{x}\right)\vec{k}\right]$$

Let's say that in your case the particle has the initial velocity $\vec{v}=\left(v_{x},0,0\right)$ and it enters into an area with magnetic field $\vec{B}=\left(0,0,B_{z}\right)$. The magnetic Lorentz force will be:
$$\vec{F}=-qv_{x}B_{z}\vec{j}$$
If the particle is positively charged (e.g. $q=e$) it will have a force component oriented towards the negative $y$ axis as in the formula above and as in your figure. If the particle is negatively charged (e.g. $q=-e$) the force component will be oriented towards positive $y$ axis.