# How electron get deflected in magnetic field while moving?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I don't understand why electron moves this way... e.g. A light object ([crampled paper](http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/fa7/wrinkled-crumpled-paper-1196284.jpg)) going down until gets hit by the wind will go parallel (at least a few seconds) to the wind direction ... why not with electron?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For electrons the magnetic field is not like a "wind". The electron experiences a velocity dependent force, the Lorentz force, which is perpendicular to both the direction of the velocity and to the magnetic field direction. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force .

Comment: Yes, but **why, what is the reason?** for it moving that way    :)      I guess the OP might already know the Lorentz Force part, but not the magnetic moment details of the electron. Although I would not be surprised  if there was a duplicate of this.

Comment: @ CountTo10 - The OP thinks of the magnetic field as of a "wind" without any basis for this assertion. He/she wonders why the electron doesn't move like a little piece of paper in a ventilator. This cannot by any means be based on a knowledge of the Lorentz force. Furthermore, the magnetic dipole moment has not been considered here. It would add a small force in an inhomogeneous magnetic field. Do you know the "reason" for the Lorentz force or of any physical force for that matter?

Comment: Sorry freecharly, I worded my last comment very badly. I think there is a way of answering the question about **why** using the precession / nutation of the electron spin as a starting point, a bit like the  Larmour Effect. If you read Wikipedia or even on this site, there is a bit of debate about this.

Comment: @ CountTo10 - I doubt that the OP here has had any thoughts about the effects of electron spin and its magnetic moment in this situation.

Comment: You are right, I'm sure. I completely self study and I went from using one  assumption to support another assumption. Not a good habit :)

Answer (score 0):

Some basics at the beginning:

- an electron, moving parallel to a magnetic field won't be deflected
- a positron as well as a proton will be deflected in the opposite direction to the direction of an electron or a antiproton
- during deflection these particles emit photons
- loosing energy these particles slowing down, the deflection will has a spiral path and at the end the particles get stopped.

Another important facts:

- all these particles have magnetic dipole moments and an intrinsic spin
- due to the [Einstein-de Haas-*experiment*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect) this spin has an angular momentum
- the axis of the spin and the direction of the magnetic dipole moment are parallel or antiparallel
- is parallel and antiparallel is a convention, but if for an electron it will be defined as parallel, than for a antiproton it is also parallel (and the antiproton will be deflected in the same direction as the electron) and for positrons and protons it will be antiparallel

> How electron get deflected in magnetic field while moving

To stick it together one has to recognise that the external magnetic field will align the electrons magnetic dipole moment, this led to the emission of photons, this to a disalignment and ... The game starts again as long as the electron has kinetic energy. More in detail see my elaboration [About the internal cause of Lorentz force](https://www.academia.edu/12037987/About_the_internal_cause_of_Lorentz_force_electric_and_magnetic_induction_English_Deutsch_)

Comment: +1  I think if similar effects can be explained by incorporating dipole moments, I cannot understand why the same cannot be applied to this  effect.

Comment: I don't understand your statement about the emission of photons. This would cause the electron(s) to loose energy, but the magnetic force $\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{b}$ does no work.

Comment: @chase Well, the external magnetic field acts like a spring due to the oscillating alignment / disalignment of the electron and by this does not get weaker nor do work. But the electrons in fact radiate (it is measurable and in particle colliders this is dangerous for life), loose by this kinetic energy and goes not in circles but has a spiral path until it exhaust its energy and stops.

Comment: Will electrons allign like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oyE8A.png ?

Comment: Yes, the electron will tend to be aligned in this way. For a non moving electron this will happens exactly, for a moving electron it doesn't fulfill because of the emission of photon and disalignment again (gyroscopic effect).

Comment: @HolgerFiedler okay, you are talking about synchrotron radiation due to radial acceleration, but that is likely a very negligible effect over the dimensions suggested by OP's diagram. In any case the question is about _why_ the particle is deflected. Synchrotron radiation is a consequence of the curved trajectory, not the cause of it. If you took away the magnetic field and tied the electron to a string and whirled it round in a circle it will still undergo synchrotron radiation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your diagram, but it might not be obvious.

To start with, in your example you have the wind moving, but a static magnetic field. That is not the same. A correct analogy would be to turn the fan off. So in that case, the "light object" would simply fall right through the area between N and S.

Now recall that electrons are spinning (well, sort of). So let us spin the "light object", very rapidly. Now as it drops the spinning will entrain the air, a fluid, and cause a force at right angles to it's motion. This is due to the Magnus effect (well, sort of) and you can see it working [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ao8RfUermdw), which would go around in circles except for the rudder.

And that's basically the answer. The electron is "spinning" at a ridiculous rate and passing through a medium that is effectively a perfect fluid. The interaction between the two causes a force that is at right angles to the direction of motion.

Comment: It's unclear if you're referring to the intrinsic quantum spin of the electron, but in any case spin has nothing to do with the magnetic force law. A scalar charged particle (such as $\pi^\pm$) will obeys exactly the same law.